# MySql make like a rollback some times automatically

Tags: database, innodb

We have many computers with POS system, each one of them have an local database where we register all sales, and at finish of the day, we take the data and insert in a master database, at the moment we have observed that in some computers, MySQL make like a rollback, for example, when we install the system in our table config have the auto increment id, and set the first sale with and id 1000, and this id change in the other sale at 1001, 1002, 1003, etc. But one day, when the id was 5000, the database reset all data in tables and start again in 1000, have you some idea what could be happening.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need more details to understand what happened.  Here's some info that may explain it anyway:

After MySQL is shutdown, or crashes (power failure, etc), and is restarted, the first thing to be done for each InnoDB table with an `AUTO_INCREMENT` it so compute the next id as `SELECT MAX(id)+1 FROM tbl`.

Even if this does not explain your situation, here is a gotcha that may bite you:

1. create id 1234 (and `COMMIT` it)
2. delete 1234 (and `COMMIT`)
3. restart mysql (gracefully or due to crash)
4. The next id to be created will be 1234.  This can be bad if you assume an id cannot be reused.

If the restart had not happened, step 4 would have created 1235, and 1234 would be forever "burned".

(Note: Version 8.0 changes this behavior.)

Comment: The problem is that not only happen with the ID, is with all data, all records inserted 3 months ago was deleted and the database start like the first time that was configured, like a rollback

Comment: That can't happen without some other action -- such as a DBA reloading a point-in-time dump.  Is replication involved?  Do you protect from "SQL injection"?  Was your site hacked?  Do you have the binlogs going back far enough to look for a naughty `DELETE`?  Etc.

Comment: Excuse me, can you tell me how I can access to the binlogs, I'm beginner in this subject, thanks

Comment: They won't exist unless `log_bin` was turned on in `my.cnf`.  `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'log_bin';` will either say `OFF` or give you the "base name" for the log(s): https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-binary-log.html  Then use mysqlbinlog to peek into it: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlbinlog.html

Comment: Ok, I activete right now, in the server logs there a log like that InnoDB: Server crash and restore, can you think that happened, if it is  ... how I can set like last restore the database of the before day?

Comment: Too much for this forum.  See point-in-time-recovery.  See delayed Slave.